# perf fails to work on really large process

Tags: ubuntu, perf, perf-event

I use perf quite often to profile my applications. Recently I got a few new machine with ~750G RAM each. I am trying to profile a process that uses about 400G of ram on one of them. This works fine on all the new machines but one. They were all installed the same way, running ubuntu.

I tried both `perf` as installed through `apt-get` and compiled my own [from git](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git).

When running `./perf top -p 14182` I some time manage to get results (after a long wait, and very rarely) but most other times I am getting:

```
The sys_perf_event_open() syscall returned with 3 (No such process) for event (cycles:pp).
/bin/dmesg may provide additional information.
No CONFIG_PERF_EVENTS=y kernel support configured?
```

For the same pid(!).

I get similar problems when trying to record, for instance:

```
time ./perf record -F 111 -a -g -p 14182 -- sleep 3
Warning:
PID/TID switch overriding SYSTEMsleep: Terminated

Command exited with non-zero status 255
2.66user 91.58system 1:36.68elapsed 97%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 4896maxresident)k 
0inputs+5248outputs (0major+4847minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

This command takes way longer than 3 seconds, I cannot ctrl+c it, and killing it requires `-9`. It emits some data into `perf.data` but when I try to view it, i get `file has no samples`.

Everything works just fine on other (smaller) processes on this machine, and as I mentioned earlier this works great on the rest of the machines, for processes weighting about 200G. When I run the previous command on the other machines, it also uses much less cpu (33% rather than 97%).

I am not sure where else to look, and google has not been very helpful for me. Any ideas or directions?

**Edit**

Seeing how system was high, I ran this with `strace -c`, this is what I get:

Another machines with a process weighting ~200G:

```
_ strace  -c perf record -F 111 -a -g -p 27879 -- sleep 3 

Warning:
PID/TID switch overriding SYSTEM[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.684 MB perf.data (~29876 samples) ]
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 91.43    2.548664         109     23481           read
  2.47    0.068712          11      6457        15 stat
  2.42    0.067392           9      7303           write
  0.68    0.018960          12      1646           getdents
  0.68    0.018841          22       847         1 mmap
```

This machine with a process weighting ~400G:

```
_ strace -c perf record -F 111 -a -g -p 14182 -- sleep 3                                                                                                                                                                                           /tmpvaknins9@snlp-brevis-3
Warning:
PID/TID switch overriding SYSTEMsleep: Terminated
sleep: Terminated
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 99.70  131.243199         472    278178           read
  0.16    0.207757           8     25895           write
  0.04    0.048962           8      6398         5 stat
  0.02    0.031247          14      2217           mmap
  0.02    0.026385           9      3091           close
```

It seems lots of time is being spent on reading `/proc/tid/maps|status`.. Perhaps my process is simply too large? Any clues how I could still get it to record this process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I experienced something similar, but less severe.

In my case, I would get the `CONFIG_PERF_EVENTS` error maybe 10% of the time.  The rest of the time `perf record` would complete without error, but it would fail to record any samples (looking at the output file with `perf report` would state "file has no samples", and `perf report -D ... | grep -c RECORD_SAMPLE` would confirm a count of zero).

Following the advice in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21155354/perf-data-file-has-no-samples), I added the `-e cpu-clock` parameter to `perf record`.  This did not fix the CONFIG_PERF_EVENTS error, and `perf record` would still take 2x-4x as long as I specified via `sleep` - but at least it worked.  Maybe it will help you, too.